# Sort by Date (Month Year) in PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have checked everywhere on SOF, but unable to find solution for it. I have date which is `month` and `year` like this coming from mysql. My sql query is using date format like this `DATE_FORMAT( month,  '%m %Y' )`

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 12 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 6000
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [month] => 07 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 1200
        )
```

Here is my sort function..

```
$MyResult = Company::Sorting($Result,'month');


public static function vpbxSorting_2($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    asort($b, 1);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}
```

It gives me sorting like this which is not correct..

```
print_r($MyResult );
```

Sort below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 01 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 1200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => 02 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 7200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => 04 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 1200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => 04 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 7200
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => 05 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 1200
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [month] => 05 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 13200
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [month] => 06 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 9600
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [month] => 06 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 6000
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [month] => 07 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 14400
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [month] => 07 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 6000
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [month] => 08 2017
            [bundle_Price] => 1200
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [month] => 08 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 6000
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [month] => 09 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 17500
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [month] => 10 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 1200
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [month] => 12 2016
            [bundle_Price] => 6000
        )

)
```

but i want it to sort like by MonthYear in DESC order... The order in above array is not correct after sorting..

The below sort order is in Desc order of month and year.

```
.. so on....
[month] => 03 2017
[month] => 02 2017
[month] => 01 2017
[month] => 12 2016
[month] => 11 2016
[month] => 10 2016
[month] => 09 2016
... so on...
```

I want to order by `[month]` field in array, not by `[bundle_price`], But bundle_price should be there in array.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the output the intended result? Also, you want to order first by month then by year but the bundle_price is irrelevant?

Comment: I want to order by `[month] ` field in array, not by `[bundle_price`], But bundle_price should be there in array.

Comment: What about the year? It should be month and then year, otherwise will having something like this `03 2017, 04 2016, 05 2017...`

Comment: Is it possible to change your database so that month and year are stored in separate fields? This would make the sorting much easier.

Comment: is it too late to change your data format? YYYY MM would ***greatly*** simplify your task. Then you can just `ORDER BY DATE (DESC)` In fact, making it an INT, rather than a string would be more efficient & still easy to format in PHP for display.

Comment: @Mawg Thanks alot, I have changed the date format in query and it work You can post your answer, i will accept,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it too late to change your data format?

YYYY MM would ***greatly*** simplify your task.

Then you can just `ORDER BY DATE (DESC)`

In fact, making it an INT, rather than a string would be more efficient & still easy to format in PHP for display.

Comment: I have changed the date format to `DATE_FORMAT( month,  '%Y %m' )` instead of `DATE_FORMAT( month,  '%m %Y' )` and it worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You need to do few steps to achieve this.

Make `strtotime` of each month variable and then do sort.

```
$tempArray = [];
for($x = 0; $x < count($myResult); $x++){
    $tempArray[strtotime($myResult['month])] = $myResult[$x];
}
```

In `tempArray` you will be having keys of only strtotime result of each month. Now you need to do sory.

```
$keys = sort(array_keys($tempArray));
```

Now you can `print_r($myResult)` and the result will be as per your expectation.